# Can't figure out what's wrong with my merge sort c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I honestly can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've been staring at this thing in the debugger for hours upon hours now, and it seems to copy the elements to the aux array correctly, but then something goes wrong, and I can't figure out what. The program compiles, the elements just aren't being sorted correctly.

```
 void merge(int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    T* aux = new T[(hi - lo) + 1];
    int i = lo;
    int j = mid + 1;

    for (int k = 0; k <= (hi - lo); k++) {  
        if (i > mid) {                              
            aux[k] = arrayData[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if (j > hi) {                          
            aux[k] = arrayData[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (arrayData[i] < arrayData[j]) {         
            aux[k] = arrayData[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {                                      
            aux[k] = arrayData[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
        arrayData[i] = aux[i - lo];
    }
    delete[] aux;
}

void mergeSort(int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi)
        return;
    int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;

    mergeSort(lo, mid);
    mergeSort((mid + 1), hi);
    merge(lo, mid, hi);
}
```

T is a template I established somewhere else in my code. As for arrayData, it's all in my class. The elements in arrayData are being moved around, just not correctly for some reason, the problem I'm 100% sure is somewhere in the code above.

Comment: `merge(lo, mid, hi)` <-- this call looks suspicious to me.  Why did you add it there?

Comment: related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It calls the function directly above it. It's meant to merge the separate pieces back together in the correct order. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Start with writing a unit test; with some known in put and an expected output.  You can then step through it when the expected doesn't match the actual.    Aside:  Are you sure you can't use std::sort?

Comment: So it turns out I'm a massive idiot. There's actually nothing wrong with the above code, the problem stemmed from calling the function in my main incorrectly, the hi parameter was much smaller than my array was. I was using the debugger to look at mergeSort do everything correctly, but then scratch my head at why the sorting was starting fresh every certain amount of values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the above code, I checked it myself using some examples. Make sure you call the sort function correctly. That is `mergeSort(0, array_size-1)`